# Convert myEnum to Color enum

Tags: c#, colors, enums

I have enum with 15 possibilities (myEnum). I want each possible of myEnum to have a different color (of color's enum).

I tried to use Color.FromArgb, but it didn't change the color.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Is it a Java question? If true, please edit your question to add the tag.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it didn't change the color'? What were you trying to do exactly? Is it a windows application? A console one? Post more information and your code.